# Examples of right ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could anyone provide me with easy examples of right ideals in a ring? I need something which advanced high-school students might easily understand.....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the rings need to be non-commutative?

Comment: If the ring is commutative, you can take the ideal generated by any element. For example, in Z, you can consider any ideal, set of multiples of an integer n. It's a two sided ideal.

Comment: Well, I was rather thinking about a right ideal which were not at the same time a left ideal.

Comment: For an ideal of a non commutative ring, say the ring of 2x2 matrices with real entrie, you can take the set [a b 0 0] as a and b are real.(sorry for nt being able to write a matrix down) which is a right sided ideal, if I remember well, but not a left sided

Comment: you mean a and b as the top row of the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling some answers from the comments:

- If $\mathbb M_n$ is the set of $n \times n$ matrices over your favorite ring, $I \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is some subset of indices and $R_I \subseteq \mathbb M_n$ is the subset of matrices whose only nonzero entries are in rows whose indices are in $I$, then $R_I$ is a right ideal.  If $I$ is a proper subset of the indices then this is not a left ideal.
- If $R$ is any ring and $x \in R$ then $xR$ is a right ideal.  If $R$ is noncommutative then this is likely not a left ideal, but you have to check this case by case.  For instance in the ring $R = k\langle x, y\rangle$ of noncommutative polynomials $xR$ is the set of all polynomials of the form $xf(x, y)$ and this is not a left ideal.

Comment: I am pleased to provide the link to a paper of mine on right ideals and their role in human language (particularly, in the so-called sublanguages) which I finished some weeks ago and which has been uploaded at Arxiv. I hope to have done justice in the footnotes and acknowledgements to all te people who have helped me in this forum. Feedback will me welcome. http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01032